# Find Nth prime - Where N < 10000

Tags: java, primes

```
public static List<Integer> storePrimes(){
        int limit = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10;
        boolean primes[] = new boolean[limit];
        List<Integer> primeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int i = 2;
        while(primeList.size() <= 10001){
            while(true){
                if(primes[i] == false){
                    primeList.add(i);
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }

            for(int j = i; j < limit; j += i){
                primes[j] = true;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return primeList;
    }
```

I want to find Nth primes. I am using this function to store all N primes. Later I can easily get Nth prime from list instead of doing everytime. N here is 10000.

How could I improve this code? What is the best upperlimit of an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How many?

[How many primes are there less than N?](https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html)

The short answer is that you should have somewhere between 100,000 and 1,000,000 entries in the array.  There's a table that says that there are less than 10,000 primes before 100,000.

> ```
>         int limit = Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10;
> ```

You can calculate this based on N.  So assuming you pass N as a parameter to the method:

```
        final int LIMIT = 2 * N * (int)Math.log(N);
```

Would contain the necessary number of primes consistently.  You could probably get away with a considerably smaller number than 2.  E.g. 1.1 would likely also work.

I made `LIMIT` final and capitalized it.  It's not going to change, so we may as well make note of that.

#### Match name to function

> ```
>         boolean primes[] = new boolean[limit];
> ```

You call this `primes`, but the prime values are `false`.  I would change this to `composites`.  Then it makes more sense for `false` to mean that it is prime.  You may even want to call it something like `compositeStatuses` or `factorableStatuses` to make that meaning clearer.

#### Optimize

> ```
>             for(int j = i; j < limit; j += i){
> ```

You can actually do fewer than this:

```
            for (int j = i * i; j < LIMIT; j += i) {
```

This works because the first `i` multiples will have already been marked `false` by previous primes.  For example, when `i` is 2, then this starts at 4.  For 3, this starts at 9.  The only multiple between 3 and 9 is 6 which was marked false when `i` was 2.  In general, if a multiple is less than `i * i`, it will have been seen previously because it must be a multiple of `i` and something smaller than `i`.  All primes smaller than `i` have already been found.  The `i * i` value is the first multiple that we've never seen previously.

I added some extra spaces for readability as well.

#### Readability

> ```
>         while(primeList.size() <= 10001){
>             while(true){
>                 if(primes[i] == false){
>                     primeList.add(i);
>                     break;
>                 }
>                 i++;
>             }
>
>             for(int j = i; j < limit; j += i){
>                 primes[j] = true;
>             }
>             i++;
>         }
> ```

I would find this easier to read as

```
        for (int i = 2; i < LIMIT; i++) {
            if (composites[i] == false) {
                primeList.add(i);
                if (primeList.size() >= N) {
                    break;
                }

                for (int j = i * i; j < LIMIT; j += i) {
                    composites[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

This also explicitly handles the case where you try to go past the end of the array.  And it returns just `N` primes.  The original code would return 10,002 primes when you only needed 10,000.

I find it easier to follow without the infinite loop.  Now we can see that we are iterating from 2 to `LIMIT` checking if each value is prime.  There's only one loop that changes `i` so it's easy to understand what happens on each iteration.

Comment: Don't compare `if (composites[i] == false)`. Just use `if(!composites[i])`